# Openvpn configuration Issue

Tags: 14.04, vpn, openvpn

I am using ubuntu 14.04 lts and the error i get while configuring my openvpn file is that.
The file 'TunnelBear Germany.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information
Error: unknown error.
Not just germany but every country sv file has this issue my vpn "tunnelbear" said they support linux but don't provide troubleshooting.

Not just germany but every sv has the issue.I did follow the instructions as given on the site which i have linked below.
How do i fix this ?
Here is a link to config file [config file](http://pastebin.com/c8CwzSVu)

[Instructions on the vpn service site](https://www.tunnelbear.com/updates/linux_support/)

I have been stuck on windows due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, open a terminal and run these commands: or `cd` into the unzipped directory and then run `sudo openvpn --config "TunnelBear Germany.ovpn"`:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/tunnelbear/linux/openvpn.zip

unzip openvpn.zip

cd openvpn

sudo openvpn --config "TunnelBear Germany.ovpn"
```

Enter your password for sudo, then vpn username and vpn password. Keep the terminal open and do not close it until you are ready to stop the VPN; closing the terminal closes the VPN session. Also, the terminal will output realtime status and error messages so you can keep tabs on the tunnel status.

I guess you have to run the command from the directory that contains all the files (cert key etc), otherwise the config file won't know where to find them. That is not typical of openvpn client files but they all (different vpn providers) seem to have their own (slight) unique differences.

---

These commands replace the "tb-downloader.sh" script from github in case you tried using that as the original script fails to rename the files as country.ovpn.

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/tunnelbear/linux/openvpn.zip; unzip openvpn.zip

mv openvpn tunnelbear.d; cd tunnelbear.d

for f in *.ovpn; do mv "$f" `echo $f | sed 's/ //g;s/TunnelBear//g'`; done

cd ..; chmod 600 tunnelbear.d/*; sudo chown root:root tunnelbear.d/*
```

Answer (score 0):

i quickly set up a fresh ubuntu 14.04.2 and created a free beartunnel account.
there might be two problems:

- are you using the free "Little Bear" account? because they mention something like

> Linux tunneling is only available for paid Giant or Grizzly accounts

- which openvpn version are you using? run `dpkg -l | grep openvpn`
  openvpn mentions a bug with [v2.3.4 and TLSv1.2](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/401)

also please post the content of your /var/log/syslog, where it is starting with

> .... ubuntu-gui NetworkManager[734]:  Starting VPN service 'openvpn'...

Comment: no,i actually have a paid grizzly account